# mypy gives an error: "Name is not defined" when referring an alias with a package name prefix

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to provide better type annotations for native library wrapped in Python package using stub files.

Consider the following toy example:
Package structure:

```
. geometry
|- typing
|  `- __init__.pyi
|- geometry.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
|- __init__.py
|- __init__.pyi
`- py.typed
```

Stub files have the following content:

`geometry/typing__init__.pyi`

```py
import geometry
import typing

Point = tuple[int, int]
Primitive = geometry.Circle | geometry.Rect
Primitives = typing.Sequence[Primitive]
```

`geometry/__init__.pyi`

```py
import geometry.typing


class Circle:
    center: geometry.typing.Point
    radius: int

    def __init__(self, center: geometry.typing.Point, radius: int): ...


class Rect:
    top_left: geometry.typing.Point
    width: int
    height: int

    def __init__(self, top_left: geometry.typing.Point, width: int, height: int): ...


def calculate_union_area(primitives: geometry.typing.Primitives) -> float: ...
```

`geometry/__init__.py`

```py
from .geometry import Circle, Rect, calculate_union_area
```

Running `mypy.stubtest` via: `python -m mypy.stubtest geometry` gives the following output:

```
error: not checking stubs due to mypy build errors:
geometry/__init__.pyi:4: error: Name "geometry.typing.Point" is not defined  [name-defined]
geometry/__init__.pyi:7: error: Name "geometry.typing.Point" is not defined  [name-defined]
geometry/__init__.pyi:10: error: Name "geometry.typing.Point" is not defined  [name-defined]
geometry/__init__.pyi:14: error: Name "geometry.typing.Point" is not defined  [name-defined]
geometry/__init__.pyi:16: error: Name "geometry.typing.Primitives" is not defined  [name-defined]
```

If I try to use types from `geometry.typing` in external file:

```py
import geometry
import geometry.typing

from geometry.typing import Point


def foo(pt: Point) -> None:
    print(pt)

foo((1, 2))
foo(('bar', 31))

def baz(primitives: geometry.typing.Primitives) -> None:
    print(len(primitives))

baz([geometry.Circle([0, 0], 3)), geometry.Rect((1, 2), width=10, height=10)])
```

Type hints and autocompletion from pylance and pyright language servers are working as expected.

Invoking mypy as `python -m mypy --strict --follow_imports_for_stubs main.py` on above example again gives an error regarding usage of `geometry.typing.Primitives` annotation: `Name "geometry.typing.Primitives" is not defined  [name-defined]`, but resolves `Point` name and even its type complaining about wrong usage in `foo(('bar', 31))`.

Versions:

- mypy version: 0.991
- python version: 3.10.9

So, the question is the following:

**How make mypy happy when using alias types by their full names?**

NOTE: Changing `geometry.typing.__init__.pyi` to `geometry.typing.__init__.py` with

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    # same content goes here
```

does nothing - errors are still there.

NOTE: Using `from geometry.typing import Name` form is not the case, because in the real example there might be name collisions between modules.

NOTE: Using `from geometry.typing import Name as geometry_typing_Name` form is not the case too, because it looks ugly and apart from that it is a crutch to resolve possible mypy checker issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that i solved like in the discussion here https://github.com/konradhalas/dacite/issues/133

in your case it would involve playing around the idea of adding in your init.pyi files (probably in this one: geometry/typing__init__.pyi) something like

```
__all__ = [
"Point",
"Primitives"]
```

see also the discussion here about this__all__: [What does __all__ mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python)